# Docker - Publish localhost HTTPS server from container to host

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, https, tls1.2

I have built my docker image to run an HTTPS Node.js server locally with all TLS certificates required and well configured:

```
...
var port = config.port || 9010, https;
var tlsOptions = {
    pfx: fs.readFileSync('./tls/keystore.p12'),
    passphrase: ******,
    honorCipherOrder: true,
    secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3    
};
try {
    https = require('https').Server(tlsOptions, app);
} catch (e) {
    console.error('Fail to start HTTPS server ' + e);
}
...
```

I have tested successfully it inner the container, and also in the host, using `curl`.

I would now publish `https://localhost:9010` of the container binding it with `https://localhost:9010` of docker's host. I have used the following command:

```
docker container run --publish 9010:9010 --detach --name https_server_container https_server:1.0
```

When I run curl `https://localhost:9010`from docker's host, my local machine, I receive this error:

```
curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
```

I have tried to follow docker doc [Protect the Docker daemon socket](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) but nothing.

What steps should I follow to publish correctly the https node server in the container?

Thanks

Comment: The service inside the container needs to listen on 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces) or else it can't be reached from outside the container.  Are you setting that correctly, or is it listening only on the container-private `localhost`?

Comment: Hi David, thanks a lot for your comment. It resolved my issue! My Node.js server listened on 127.0.0.1 and not in 0.0.0.0, I changed in 0.0.0.0 and I can now reach it from docker's host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze) I changed the server host of my Node.js server runned in the docker container from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`.

```
...
https.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    ...
});
```

In this manner I can now reach from my docker host the server in the docker container via https://localhost:9010/.

Answer (score 1):

Way I see it there is some typo with docker command :

```sh
docker container run --publish 9010:9010 --detach --name https_server_container https_server:1.0
```

you need to space( ) between 9010 and --detach

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but It was a typing error in the question. I have executed the command with spaces between 9010 and --detach